# Off-kilter design style

Tags: interface-design, terminology, trends

I'm trying to recall what this style is called where it's super minimal, there's a light use of shapes to guide the attention and the shapes and text are slightly out of kilter to each other. Does anyone know what this is called?
[image]

Comment: Material Design?

Comment: Maybe look into Swiss or International style?

Answer (score 1):

I would call it ultra contemporary or minimalist with hierarchal and visual weight.

It looks very "Bauhaus". Their design philosophy revolved around things being:

- minimalist
- geometrical
- anti-ornamental
- hierarchical